using awk print all lines starting with `* foo` to any following line that starts with `* `
Print all lines that start with * foo to any next line that starts with * 
I thought that this would work, but it only prints the first lines:
awk '/^\* foo/,/^\* /' file.org

results in:
* foo

example file (org-mode):
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar
** subheading
more text


what is your desired output?

awk '/^* foo/ {prn=1; print; next} /^* / {prn=0} prn {print}' file ??

@jhnc I'm really just trying to find a maintainable way to parse and analyze sets of org-mode files

in mathematics, intervals can be open or closed: (start,end), [start,end], (start,end], [start,end). It is unclear without sample output if you want [start,end] or [start,end)

@jhnc that is true, I suppose though that awk doesn't have a command line flag to say "always assume intervals are (start, end)" (which is what I was after)?

(start,end) excludes both start and end. I guess you mean you want [start,end]

oh true, I thought that you meant that awk would ignore the first line on the second run. But you can interpret it that it would include the start (the first line), but also exclude that last line (no need to display whichever heading was next), so it would be [start,end)

yes, that's why I asked for your desired output in my first comment

my analogy with intervals assumes start!=end, so is not ideal

sorry for the confusion, the answer you submitted though interpreted my intentions correctly (except for inclusion of the last line).

That "except for inclusion of the last line" at the end of your comment is the biggest clue to what you're actually trying to do, what the ^*  lines from your sample input actually mean, and so what the right solution would be. You don't have start-end delimiters in your data, you just have start header lines for blocks of text and so a solution shouldn't be about start-end ranges, it should be about start-before_next_start blocks.

Given your response to the other answer it appears you want output for your sample to be:
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar

For this, you might be able to use sed which unlike awk does not check both start and end condition on the same iteration:
sed -n '/^\* foo/,/^\* /p' file.org


Note that more complicated input may not produce the output you want. For example, this input:
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* foo too
** should this print?
- or this?
* bar
** subheading
more text


hmm, that doesn't seem to work - I'm getting sed: -e expression #1, char 16: missing command. sed (GNU sed) 4.9 Packaged by Debian 2022

regarding the example of a more complicated output I think that it wouldn't be a problem, as you could make the pattern more specific, e.g. ^\* foo$.

better than using a more specific regex is to define what you want the output to be - then people wouldn't have to guess!

sorry, forgot to add the scaffolding to the sed command

brilliant, that works. Sorry again for the confusing question. I also shouldn't have assumed that awk is necessary for this task. Thank you for explaining how sed works. I've been trying to run a similar command before, but got lost in the details. This works really well and maybe will be also extensible in the future for more complex queries.

I just re-read your question and comments and I now think that * foo and * bar are header lines for the block of text under them (so you won't want the * bar line printed when printing the * foo block for that reason) and in that case you should not be doing what I show in my original answer below, nor what's shown in any of the other answers as they all treat/consume the * bar line as the end of the * foo block and so make it harder to treat it consistently with the way * foo is treated as the start of it's own separate block. You should be doing this instead:
$ awk -F'^[*] ' -v tgt='foo' '
    NF>1  { printf "%s", block; block=""; inTgt=($2 == tgt) }
    inTgt { block = block $0 ORS }
    END   { printf "%s", block }
' file
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments

With that approach if you wanted to print multiple blocks it's trivial to extend it while keeping the same code structure and avoid duplicating tests, e.g. to print both the foo block and the bar block:
$ awk -F'^[*] ' -v tgts='foo,bar' '
    BEGIN { split(tgts,tmp,/,/); for (i in tmp) tgtsArr[tmp[i]] }
    NF>1  { printf "%s", block; block=""; inTgt=($2 in tgtsArr) }
    inTgt { block = block $0 ORS }
    END   { printf "%s", block }
' file
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar
** subheading
more text

Obvious you can change , in tgts=foo,bar to be whatever separator you like and you can use regexp instead of string comparisons if you prefer.
I'd actually go a step further and put the block-processing in a function so you can then do any further processing with the block before deciding to print it or not, e.g. to print any block that starts with foo or bar but only if it contains the string more text:
$ awk -F'^[*] ' -v tgts='foo,bar' '
    BEGIN { split(tgts,tmp,/,/); for (i in tmp) tgtsArr[tmp[i]] }
    NF>1  { prt(); block=""; inTgt=($2 in tgtsArr) }
    inTgt { block = block $0 ORS }
    END   { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( block ~ "more text" ) {
            printf "%s", block
        }
    }
' file
* bar
** subheading
more text

or to isolate all comparisons/decisions inside the prt() function:
$ awk -F'^[*] ' -v tgts='foo,bar' '
    BEGIN { split(tgts,tmp,/,/); for (i in tmp) tgtsArr[tmp[i]] }
    NF>1  { prt(); hdr=$2 }
    { block = block $0 ORS }
    END   { prt() }

    function prt() {
        if ( hdr in tgtsArr ) {
            if ( block ~ "more text" ) {
                printf "%s", block
            }
        }
        block = ""
    }
' file
* bar
** subheading
more text

Hopefully it's obvious the flexibility and extensibility you get with the above approach.

Original answer:
To have awk not match the same line as /^\* foo/ when looking for /^\* / you could just keep a count of the times /^\* / matched after /^\* foo/ did and if it's non-zero then that is the "first /^\* / after /^\* foo/'" which is the actual end condition you want, e.g.:
$ awk '/^\* foo/,/^\* / && c++' file
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar

but don't do that, use a flag rather than a range expression if you think you might want to build on this to do different things and/or if you care about efficiency.
For example, the above assumes you always want to print the start and end lines of the target block but maybe you don't (now or in future). One of the following might be what you want to do.

Print start and end delimiting lines:

$ awk '/^\* foo/{f=1} f{print; if (/^\* / && c++) exit}' file
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar


Print no delimiting lines:

$ awk 'f{if (/^\* /) exit; print} /^\* foo/{f=1}' file
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments


Print start but not end delimiting line:

$ awk '/^\* foo/{f=1} f{if (/^\* / && c++) exit; print}' file
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments


Print end but not start delimiting line:

$ awk 'f{print; if (/^\* /) exit} /^\* foo/{f=1}' file
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar

or one of many other possible permutations of that or similar code depending on several unstated requirements. For example change exit to f=c=0 if you want to match multiple blocks from the input. I'm using exit for optimum efficiency so awk doesn't continue reading the rest of the input once the target block has been printed but using f=c=0 (which would give you the same "read the whole file" behavior as a range expression in sed or awk) might be adequate if your input file is less than a few thousand lines.
Some posts related to issues you're likely to come across with the pattern matching you appear to be trying to do:

Is a /start/,/end/ range expression ever useful in awk? - why to use a flag (f) and/or count (c above) variable instead of a range expression.
Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern - ways to print some number of lines before/after a pattern is matched.
How do I find the text that matches a pattern? - issues related to partial vs full and regexp vs string pattern matching.


Thank you for the answer and apologies for accepting the other answer that used sed - it was just much simpler and solved my badly presented problem. Technically your answer is more correct.

You're welcome. No need to apologize, you should always accept the answer that works best for you.

awk '/^\* foo/,/^\* /' file.org

Observe that any line matching /^\* foo/ does also match /^\* / thus printing is turned on and turned off at same line. You should inform GNU AWK that printing should be turned off if line is not starting with * foo and is starting with *  you can do it following way
awk '/^\* foo/,!/^\* foo/&&/^\* /' file.org

Explanation: ! is negation (logical NOT) and && is logical AND, for file.org content
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar
** subheading
more text

output is
* foo
** subheading
- item 1
- item2
comments
* bar

(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Thanks, that works, although it is a bit... cumbersome. Do you know if there are any awk (or sed) clones that allow for a simpler syntax (fawk?)? If not I may try then to find a proper org-mode command line parser (if one exists) as I was hoping to perform more complex queries as well (getting parents, subchildren matching patterns etc.), so not sure if this will scale.
